# Appium WinAppDriver FindElement not working. Error 400, bad request

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, ui-automation, winappdriver

I am creating a proof of concept UI Automation test to demo. When I use the inspect tool view the text box I want to input into the AutomationID is set to "Memery". I have written the following code:

```
namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class WpfTest
    {
        protected const string WindowsApplicationDriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723";
        private const string IAdminInstance = "<filepath>";

        protected static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void Setup(TestContext context)
        {
            if (session == null)
            {
                var appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();



                appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("app", IAdminInstance);

                appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "windows");

                appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("automationName", "windows");
                appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
                session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new System.Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appiumOptions);
                
            }
        }

        public static void TearDown()
        {
            // Close the application and delete the session
            if (session != null)
            {
                session.Quit();
                session = null;
            }
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test1()
        {

            var asdf = session.FindElementByWindowsUIAutomation("Memery");
            asdf.Click();
            
            int x = 2;
            Assert.AreEqual(x, 2);
          
        }

    }
}
```

which results in the following coming up in the WinAppDriver console:

```
POST /session HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, image/png
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 266
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.0 (.net windows)

{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"D:\\Projects\\gitea\\Kaiser\\Livermore\\KPCommon\\InventoryAdmin\\bin\\Debug\\InventoryAdmin.exe","platformName":"Windows","automationName":"windows","deviceName":"DRAGONITE"},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"Windows"}]}}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 203
Content-Type: application/json

{"sessionId":"E96DDBBF-F5A1-412E-AF2B-61B4D06CD6DC","status":0,"value":{"app":"D:\\Projects\\gitea\\Kaiser\\Livermore\\KPCommon\\InventoryAdmin\\bin\\Debug\\InventoryAdmin.exe","platformName":"Windows"}}


==========================================
POST /session/E96DDBBF-F5A1-412E-AF2B-61B4D06CD6DC/element HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, image/png
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 50
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.0 (.net windows)

{"using":"-windows uiautomation","value":"Memery"}
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 102
Content-Type: application/json

{"status":32,"value":{"error":"invalid selector","message":"Invalid selector: -windows uiautomation"}}
```

Here is the XAML snippit as well for the element I want

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Width="Auto" Height="35">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
         AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Memery" x:Name="operatorIDEdit"  MinWidth="175" Width="Auto" 
         TabIndex="0" Margin="0,0,20,0" GotKeyboardFocus="operatorIDEdit_GotKeyboardFocus" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: try with FindElementByAccessibilityId or one of these: https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Docs/AuthoringTestScripts.md#supported-locators-to-find-ui-elements

Comment: @pcalkins when I do that I get an error 404. In Inspect the ClassName and localizedcontroltype are too general ("TextBox") and there is no Name set. Is there something in the xaml i can set so that WinAppDriver will find my elements?

Comment: not familiar with Appium, but maybe see this page: http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/

Comment: Found my issue. I hadn't created a Windows Packaging project to deploy my application into ... seems to be functioning as expected now. Thanks for the help.